# Find Minimum and Maximum of a column in LInq query result

Tags: linq

I have an Linq query like this:

```
var result = from c in displayedEmployees select new[] { c.Name, c.Code, c.Rank.ToString(), c.Id.ToString(),c.Rank. };
```

If i want to select the min and max of any column for example Rank along with this like:

```
var result = from c in displayedEmployees select new[] { c.Name, c.Code, c.Rank.ToString(), c.Id.ToString(),min(c.Rank) ,max(c.Rank)};
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select actually performs a transformation of every item (displayedEmployee), so ends up with the same number of items as you started with. Min and max are reductions, they reduce the list into a scalar.

After the "select" keyword is a function that only recieves the current item (c in your case). So there is no way to get the max there and you don't want every item in result to repeat the same maximum value.

You should compute the minimum and maximum separately.

After:

```
var result = from c in displayedEmployees select { c.Name, c.Code, c.Rank };
```

You could do something like this:

```
var min = result.Min(x => x.Rank);
var max = result.Max(x => x.Rank);
```

See more samples here (LINQ 101): http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: if select to array `select new[]` then after selecting don't have access to field by name, so when you try ` result.Min(x => x.Rank);` will be error

Comment: Indeed, the first line in the question is not correct. I'll change my answer.